# ValueTask instances should not have their result directly accessed unless the instance has already completed

Tags: c#, .net, valuetask

There is a library returning a `ValueTask` and I have a synchronous method which is consuming the ValueTask. The issue is that there is the following warning:

> CA2012: ValueTask instances should not have their result directly accessed unless the instance has already completed. Unlike Tasks, calling Result or GetAwaiter().GetResult() on a ValueTask is not guaranteed to block until the operation completes. If you can't simply await the instance, consider first checking its IsCompleted property (or asserting it's true if you know that to be the case).

How do I fix it?

```cs
public void CreateListenKey()
{
    var result = CreateSpotListenKeyAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // CA2012: ValueTask instances should not have their result directly accessed unless the instance has already completed. Unlike Tasks, calling Result or GetAwaiter().GetResult() on a ValueTask is not guaranteed to block until the operation completes. If you can't simply await the instance, consider first checking its IsCompleted property (or asserting it's true if you know that to be the case).

    if (result.Success)
    {
        using var document = JsonDocument.Parse(result.Data!);
        lock (_listenKeyLocker)
        {
            if (document.RootElement.TryGetProperty("listenKey", out var listenKeyElement))
            {
                var listenKey = listenKeyElement.GetString();
                ListenKey = listenKey;
            }
        }
    }
}

// library
public async ValueTask<CallResult<string>> CreateSpotListenKeyAsync()
{
    var result = await SendPublicAsync<string>(
        "/api/v3/userDataStream",
        Method.Post);

    return result;
}

// Can't just make it async, because these listen key methods are used in an event handler.
private void OnKeepAliveTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    RestApi.PingListenKey();
}
```

Comment: Make `CreateListenKey` async, then await it?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, I can't. `CreateListenKey` is used in a `Timer.Elapsed` event which is synchronous.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, I could make it async, but then I would have to wrap it in a `Task.Run(() => ...);` in the `OnKeepAliveTimerElapsed`

Comment: You could use a lambda as the event handler e.g. `Timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => CreateListenKey();`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, that's bad. 1) It'll make it `async void` (fire and forget); 2) I can't unsubscribe the Elapsed event.

Comment: `ValueTask.AsTask`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, the question is: is the conversion more worthy than just making it ValueTask and then wrapping it in a `Task.Run(() => ...)` inside the Elapsed event handler?

Comment: What do you mean with "more worthy"? More expensive? If you're synchronously awaiting things you are beyond such considerations; all approaches to that are bad anyway. `Task.Run(() => ...)` tends to commission threads, so it's almost always worse than anything else. Certainly if you're doing it from an event handler -- which is itself running on a thread pool thread. Pretty soon you've got tasks and threads stacking up to high heaven to do *one* simple thing, wrapped in six layers.

Comment: @nop There's nothing inherently bad about using `async void` with an event handler. As for unsubscribing, you could if you save a reference to the delegate instance, or just create a wrapper method rather than the lambda.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, so what do you think is best to choose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way to wait synchronously the completion of a `ValueTask` is to convert it to a `Task`, with the [`AsTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.astask) method:

```
Task<CallResult<string>> task = CreateSpotListenKeyAsync().AsTask();
var result = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

if (result.Success)
{
    //...
```

In your case, and based on the implementation of the `CreateSpotListenKeyAsync` method, this conversion most likely incurs zero overhead. Assuming that the `ValueTask<CallResult<string>>` is not already completed upon creation, most likely it wraps internally a `Task<CallResult<string>>`, so the conversion will just return the wrapped task. It seems unlikely that it wraps an implementation of the [`IValueTaskSource<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.ivaluetasksource-1) interface, in which case the conversion would incur the cost of allocating a few lightweight objects.

In case you anticipate that the `ValueTask<CallResult<string>>` will be frequently completed upon creation, you could optimize your code like this:

```
var valueTask = CreateSpotListenKeyAsync();
CallResult<string> result;
if (valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
{
    result = valueTask.Result;
}
else
{
    result = valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

The intention of above code is to avoid an internal call to the [`Task.FromResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult) method, which is allocating in general.

It is also possible to optimize the synchronous waiting of `IValueTaskSource<T>`-based value tasks, but [it's not trivial](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7508080ebc58865d6ec6f151c4f58b92b0026d46/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToBlockingEnumerable.cs#L62), and the expected benefits are so minuscule that it's unlikely to worth the effort.

---

In case of a non-generic [`ValueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask), you could do what @nop suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715689/valuetask-instances-should-not-have-their-result-directly-accessed-unless-the-in/72716573#comment128619480_72716573):

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static void GetResult(this in ValueTask valueTask)
{
    if (valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        valueTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return;
    }

    valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

But it's not really needed. In case the `ValueTask` has completed successfully, the `AsTask` will never allocate, whatever is the underlying implementation of the `ValueTask`. In case it is backed by a `IValueTaskSource`, the `AsTask` will return the static singleton `Task.CompletedTask`. So doing simply `valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is pretty much the same.

Comment: Hey, I just had to do the same but for `ValueTask`, not `ValueTask<T>`. Is this correct:  https://pastebin.com/Q4UZqB40

Comment: @nop yes, it's correct, but also probably superfluous. I updated the answer to address this case too.

Comment: @nop actually in case the `valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully` is true, you can `return` immediately. The subsequent `valueTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is a no-op in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Do you mean `public static void GetResult(this in ValueTask valueTask) { if (valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully) return; valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }`

Comment: @nop yep, exactly. Although in retrospect calling invariably the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is a good idea, because it allows `IValueTaskSource`-based implementations to know that the `ValueTask` has been consumed, so that they can reuse the internal object that implements this interface.

Comment: Note: `valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` will execute synchronously and is probably not what you are wanting to acomplish.

Comment: @ElanHasson the OP has stated in the question: *"I have a synchronous method which is consuming the ValueTask"*. I think the intention to wait synchronously for the completion of the `ValueTask` is clear. If you think otherwise, you can ask the OP for a clarification by leaving a comment under the question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, you're correct. I ended up here looking for info on handling the async invocation of the `ValueTask` if `IsCompleted`  is false, which indicates it should be awaited via `AsTask()`.

Was just calling it out so others can get that information when they land here for the same.