# ValueTask to sync - Creating an extension method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have to provide a sync way for the following `ValueTask` returning method. How do I create an extension method of the following `PingSpotListenKey` method, because I have more of these method and it would be nice if I don't write the part with `IsCompletedSuccessfully` over and over again.

```cs
public CallResult<string> PingSpotListenKey(string listenKey)
{
    var valueTask = PingSpotListenKeyAsync(listenKey);
    CallResult<string> result;
    if (valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        result = valueTask.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        result = valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    return result;
}

public async ValueTask<CallResult<string>> PingSpotListenKeyAsync(string listenKey)
{
    var result = await SendPublicAsync<string>(
        "/api/v3/userDataStream",
        Method.Put,
        new Dictionary<string, object?>
        {
            { "listenKey", listenKey }
        });

    return result;
}

public async ValueTask<CallResult<string>> CreateSpotListenKeyAsync()
{
    var result = await SendPublicAsync<string>(
        "/api/v3/userDataStream",
        Method.Post);

    return result;
}
```

### Does the following work?

```cs
public static class ValueTaskExtensions
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static T GetResult<T>(this in ValueTask<T> valueTask)
    {
        if (valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
        {
            return valueTask.Result;
        }

        return valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}

public CallResult<string> PingSpotListenKey(string listenKey)
{
    return PingSpotListenKeyAsync(listenKey).GetResult();
}
```

Comment: There is *no* valid and correct implementation of "sync over sync"

Comment: by which I mean: this thing you're trying to do is explicitly contrary to the entire point of async; it is actively harmful, and can have significant impact - ranging from unnecessary overhead, past pool exhaustion, all the way to outright deadlocks. The only "good" thing about this code (and I use that term lightly) is that we can agree that it doesn't attempt to access the result of a VT twice (which is also invalid and undefined). But fundamentally, you **should not** attempt to consume async code from sync code. The other way around is fine, but this: is simply never "correct"

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks for the answer! I need it because this method is going to be invoked in a `Timer.Elapsed` event handler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715689/valuetask-instances-should-not-have-their-result-directly-accessed-unless-the-in. So it's either wrapping the async overload in a `Task.Run(...)` inside the `Timer.Elapsed`, or simply doing what's above.

Comment: using Task.Run to invoke an async chunk is fine as long as you don't immediately call `.Wait()` (etc) on the task - and as long as it doesn't throw exceptions. So: make sure you catch any error scenario (unobserved faulted tasks are *also* problematic)

Comment: So why don't you make it `async void`?

Comment: @Charlieface, ReSharper highlights it as a warning when there is async void

Comment: Perfectly reasonable to make an event handler `async void` as long as you are aware of re-entrancy, but you should not make any other functions `async void`. In other words, push your `await` code all the way up to the first event handler coming from user input. For a console application you can use `async Main`