# How can I synchronously wait for ValueTask without performance loss?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, valuetask

First of all, our platform for this question is C# 9.0 and .NET core 7.0.
Lets suppose that I have to wait for a `ValueTask` to complete in a synchronous method. When dealing with tasks in this context, I generally use the following scheme:

```
var task = Get_Task_PlaceHolderMethod();
task.Wait(timeoutedToken);
var value = task.Result // use from here
```

Otherwise I just `await`, normally.

how can I use something like this to wait for ValueTasks? They don't have any `.Wait` method and all I can do is convert it to task with `.AsTask()`, but then I will lose the benefits of the `ValueTask` creating an instance of a task to wrap it.

I tried to code some logic but always end up with less performant code than before.
As following I had to create an instance of a task, so the above implications applies too.
I have no benefit from the `ValueTask`.

```
private static void SyncallyAwait(Func<ValueTask> getTask, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var operationWaiter = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var v_task = getTask();
    var timeouter = Task.Delay(timeout, operationWaiter.Token);
    while ( // wait until done
        v_task.IsCompleted is false &&
        timeouter.IsCompleted is false
    ){ }

    if (timeouter.IsCompleted)
        throw ERROR_TaskTimeouted();

    operationWaiter.Cancel();

    if (v_task.IsCompleted is false)
        throw ERROR_TaskNotAccessible();

    //throw any resulting exception
    v_task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static readonly Func<ApplicationException> ERROR_TaskNotAccessible = () => new($"""
    Its not possible to ensure that the valuetask is done running, which means that the 
    result is not accurate or safe to access without putting the thread on deadlock.
    to prevent the unexpected lack of response this exception has been thrown
""");

private static readonly Func<TimeoutException> ERROR_TaskTimeouted = () => new($"""
    MovingOperation exceeded the sync waiter timeout. The database didn't returned in
    reasonable time expected.
""");
```

Another possibility I could try is to use the start time of the `v_task` and receive a `TimeSpan` to count the current time in the loop while, checking if the `Now - start_time` is
greater than the limit `timeSpan`. But that doesn't seem right.

Comment: As a side note, `await` means "asynchronoys wait". So the method `SyncallyAwait` is not appropriately named. `SyncallyWait` might be a better name, or simply `Wait`.

Comment: Related: [ValueTask instances should not have their result directly accessed unless the instance has already completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715689/valuetask-instances-should-not-have-their-result-directly-accessed-unless-the-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used value tasks that much. But my understanding is that the primary benefit is avoiding allocation of a `Task` object when the result is already available and the async method can complete synchronously. So I think the correct approach should be:

```
var valueTask = getTask();
if(valueTask.IsCompleted){
    return valueTask.Result;
}
return valueTask.AsTask().Result;
```

If `getTask()` was really run synchronously, then the returned value task will already be completed, and you can just check this and return the result. If it did not complete synchronously you have to convert it to a task and wait on the task. I do not see any reason why this should cause any performance impact.

Your example seem to be spinwaiting on the value task, and that is almost certainly not a good approach.

Comment: when the valueTask is called, the method returns the control with IsCompleted = true
it means that the task is completed without awaiting for anything, right? Then .Result is safe to access without dead lock possibilities i believe so, happy that it can be that simple

Comment: *`return valueTask.AsTask().Result;`* -- I think it's better to do `return valueTask.AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`, so that an exception is exposed directly, and not wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

Comment: in this case, i think its relevant to check if `valueTask.Isfaulted` before calling the `AsTask()` logic to prevent unnecessary allocations.

Comment: @JamesJonatah From `ValueTask.Result`: "his property may only be accessed once, and only after this ValueTask<TResult> has completed". IsComplete should be safe to access and should never change value from true to false.

Comment: @JamesJonatah If the task has faulted you should probably not worry about the tiny overhead of a memory allocation. If you have code that for some reasons throw exceptions with a high frequency, fix that! Exceptions are expensive to create! There are probably some edge cases where explicit checking for faults is useful, but the "premature optimization is the root of all evil" quote probably applies here.

Comment: The frequency of the exceptions thrown is important here in this case for me because they're meant to stop the application and provide me context of  what happened for me to solve it, i rarely use exceptions for something other than stopping the code completely